# Sparks when Touching Case with Thunderbolt Connector. Is this Normal?

Tags: power-supply, cable, thunderbolt

I just got a Pegasus Promise2 M4 RAID back from repair. There was a problem with the power supply. Just before I connected the Thunderbolt cable, I noticed lots of sparks between the ground of the cable and the case. See the following video how it looks like:

[image: sparks between cable shield and case]

- The Thunderbolt cable is already connected to the computer (not to the device shown in the video/photo).
- The cable works fine with any other device.
- The Pegasus Promise2 M4 shown in the video/photo has just a two wire power connector without grounding. The computer is grounded.
- I never had this effect with any other Thunderbolt device with the same computer.

**I this a normal effect or could this be an issue with the power supply?**

Comment: This is not normal at all. I do not fully understand the conditions in which this happens, you say the cable is already connected but I see you are connecting it in the video. Can you provide a block schematic including all the connections, with explaination?

Comment: And to close votes, this is about safety and not about repair or use. We have more than 350 questions tagged safety. Please use your powers wisely.

Comment: For a power supply **that is not grounded** this can be normal behavior. But if it did not show this before the repair of the supply then it can be that they replaced the RF suppression capacitor with a the wrong (too high) value. If you want to prevent this, always use supplies **with** ground and make sure it connects to a grounded mains socket. These are not very large sparks so I would not call this dangerous. Worst case your fingers might get a "tingle". And if this is a question about safety, then why is it not tagged with "safety" ?

Comment: Sparks?  They don't call it Thunderbolt for nothing.  [Sorry, I couldn't resist.]